# Displaying users individual data with firebase firestore + react with UID as oppose to the whole database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Hello!

#### so im currently building a student productivity app with react  + firebase the todo list functionality so far is working however, i want the todos for each user to be unique to them and no just giving them the whole entire databases worth of todos i finds this tricky as there isn't really any documentation on adding a user to a database and putting specific data to that specific user on the docs my question is how would i be able to do such a thing

---

github: https://github.com/yefim94/personalworkflow

code:

````
import {useEffect} from "react"
import { collection, doc, setDoc, query, getDocs, onSnapshot, addDoc, orderBy, limit, Timestamp} from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from "/Users/yefimblokh/Desktop/bigprojectbusiness/my-app/src/firebase-config"
import { auth } from '/Users/yefimblokh/Desktop/bigprojectbusiness/my-app/src/firebase-config';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  borderRadius: "15px",
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};
const Projects = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("")
  const todosRef = collection(db, "todos");
  const {uid, photoURL, displayName} = auth.currentUser;
  async function getUID () {
    return uid;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const q = query(todosRef, orderBy("createdAt"))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        let todos = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {todos.push(doc.data())})
        setTodos(todos)
      })
    }
    getData()
  }, [])
  async function openModel () {
    handleOpen()
  }
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  async function addTaskDatabase () {
     await addDoc(todosRef, {
      title: title,
      desc: desc,
      createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      uid: uid
    }) 
    setTitle("")
    setDesc("")
    handleClose()
  }
  return (
    <div style={{margin: "3em 3em 3em 3em"}}>
      <h1 style={{fontWeight: "600", position: "sticky", top: "50px", backgroundColor: "#fff"}}>Project</h1>
      <section style={{backgroundColor: "#F5FAF8", padding: "1em", borderRadius: "14px", overflow: "scroll"}}>
        <div style={{display: "flex", widtgh: "100%", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center"}}>
        <h3>To do</h3>
        <p style={{
          backgroundColor: "#E9F3F2",
          padding: "9px",
          borderRadius: "10px",
          color: "#71A399"
        }}>4</p>
        </div>
        <button style={{
          backgroundColor: "#E9F3F2",
          padding: "9px",
          borderRadius: "10px",
          color: "#71A399",
          border: "none",
          outline: "none",
          width: "100%",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }} onClick={openModel}>+</button>
              <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <h3>Add Task</h3>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Title: <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {setTitle(e.target.value)}} value={title} />
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
           Description: <input type="text"  onChange={(e) => {setDesc(e.target.value)}} value={desc}/>
          </Typography>
          <button style={{
            backgroundColor: "red",
            border: "none",
            color: "#fff",
            padding: "10px"
            ,borderRadius: "5px 10px 5px 10px",
            marginTop: "1EM",
          }} onClick={addTaskDatabase}>Add</button>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
     {todos.map((doc, key, uid) => (
          <div key={key} style={{backgroundColor: "#fff", padding: "10px", borderRadius: "10px", marginTop: "1em"}}>
          <h3>{doc.title}</h3>
          <p>{doc.desc}</p>
        </div>
     ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Projects```
````

Comment: In your `todo` schema I would add a field, lets say `owner`. When an authenticated user creates a new todo item, set the owner as the `uid` of that user. When fetching the data, query for only todos which owner is the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment above, here is an example:

Get current user:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
```

When creating a todo:

```
  async function addTaskDatabase () {
     await addDoc(todosRef, {
      title: title,
      desc: desc,
      createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      uid: uid,
      owner: user.uid //add user as owner
    }) 
  }
```

When querying all todos

```
const getData = async () => {
  const snapshot = await todosRef.where('owner', '==', user.uid).orderBy("createdAt").get()
  if (snapshot.empty) {
   console.log('No matching todos.');
   return;
  }  
  let todos = []
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {todos.push(doc.data())})
  setTodos(todos)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much nicholas!